# How to flip Facebook Live video while streaming?

Tags: facebook, video-streaming

When starting live video on Facebook from an Android phone, it's always mirrored. I want to flip it.

Looking at various tutorials, looks like they are all for Apple phones. For example:

- YouTube video: [How to reverse image Facebook live](https://youtu.be/BH2pWCrncTY).
- [TechShift - How do you flip live on Facebook on Android?](https://techshift.net/how-do-you-flip-live-on-facebook-on-android/):

  > #### How do I flip the mirror on Facebook Live?
  >
  > Underneath the filters, there’s a row of icons and one of them is what you’re looking for. In the bottom right corner, you’ll find a screwdriver and span icon. If you click on it, it will bring up the options for flipping the screen. The option you need is “Horizontal Flip” (The one on the left).

I cannot find this screwdriver and span icons.

Can you give me clear instructions on how to do this?